# jeditable - how to set the modified cell to an other value than the passed value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, jeditable

maybe I'm just not smart enough. I started working with jeditable and it works fine, but I'm stuck for hours now.

I'm using select fields, shown up on click (thanks jeditable), and I store the edited data in the DB, so far so good.

The problem, I get a result from the server side, which I have to set in the edited field. By default it will be set to the value from the selected field in the select.

I don't understand why the return started before the ajax Request is done (or started?). So its impossible to return the result. And sure, my first thought was I fire the return in the complete: function(), but no :).

```
$(".columnSelectLine").editable( function(value, settings) {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url:'/ajax/jq_ajax_scripts.php',
            type:'post',
            data:'request=wizardSaveFromTableColumnMapping&dbName='+dbName+'&dbTableName='+dbTableName+'&column='+this.id+'&value='+value,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            error: function(req) {
                alert("bad");
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
        return(result); // result is empty || return(value) works but is the commited value from the select field


    }, {
    loadurl : '/ajax/jq_ajax_scripts.php?request=wizardGetColumnMappingValues&dbName='+dbName+'&dbTableName='+dbTableName+'&id='+this.id,
    type    : 'select',
    onblur  : 'submit'  
});
```

I hope I'm just dumb and you tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look, you set result, then you call the ajax, then you run the console, then you return result, and then, one time, after maybe a second, the result comes back from server. You need to put your data and setting your data in the success handler, nowhere before...

because of this it´s called ajax, asynchronous, because your data comes back asynchronously, but you script runs synchronously through, not waiting for an answer from server, but the success handler does.

Comment: Thanks for the eye opening! I had to make the request synchronously, it is so obvious :). Thanks man!